# Prove that the Language $L=\{code(M)\;|\;L(M)\; \text{is closed under reversal}\}$ is undecideable

Tags: reductions

I want to solve this problem using Many-One-Reduction, which involves, if I understood it correctly, reducing another problem on the problem stated in the title, i.e.
$$
H \leq_M L
$$

I would try reducing the Halting problem $H$ onto $L$, because we know that $H$ is not decideable. Would this be the correct approach? If so, what would be next step and if not, which approach would be superior?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use Rice's theorem? it instantly solves this question

Comment: unfortunately not. Also, I would like to better understand the concept behind many-one reduction

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is in the right direction. You can indeed reduce the halting problem to this problem.

Big hint: For some TM $M$ and input $w$, construct $M_w$ that ignores its input and simulates $M$ on $w$, and accepts if $M$ halted. Fix some non-palindrome word of your choice, like the word $10$, and consider $L(M_w)\cup\{10\}$. What can you say about it?

Comment: intuitively I would think that $M_w$ accepts, since $10$ is not a palindrom and $M$ halted, which contradicts $A_{TM}$?

Comment: $M_w$ just runs $M$ on $w$, it doens't have anything to do with $10$. But what happens when we add $10$ to the language of $L(M_w)$? if $M$ halts on $w$ then $L(M_w)\cup\{10\}=\Sigma^*$, but if $M$ doesn't halt on $w$ then $L(M_w)\cup\{10\}=\{10\}$. Do you see why this reduction is valid?

Comment: I guess I am close to getting it right. Just a little bit more help needed. If $M$ doesn't halt on $w$, why is $L(M_w) \cup\{10\} = \{10\}$?

Comment: if $M$ doesn't halt on $w$, then $M_w$ is stuck in an infinite loop, hence it doesn't accept any word.

Comment: but in that case $M_w$ could simply reject? (if $M$ does not halt)

Comment: No, since it doesn't know that $M$ got stuck in an infinite loop. They both serve the same purpose though - a word is not in $L(M)$ only if $M$ doesn't halt on that word, or $M$ rejected that word.

Comment: so we want to avoid that $M$ gets in a loop by rejecting the non-palindrom before?

Comment: no, thats not a problem. The idea is that either $M_w$ accepts all words, or always gets stuck in an infinite loop, and hence its language is empty

Comment: thank you for your time and patience, I really appreciate it!