# Question about reduction Proof

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, turing-machines, reductions, mapreduce

I've recently seen a proof that the set of Turing machines $L = \{encode(M) |L(M) \text{is closed under reversal}\}$ is not decidable.

The proof used following idea:
Reduce from the $A_{TM}$ problem by taking input $\langle M, w \rangle$ and by constructing $M'$ such that $L(M') = \text{some language that is closed under reversal; if M accepts w}\\
L(M') = \text{some language that isn't closed under reversal}; \text{if M rejects w}$

Now, I have some confusion about this proof. I can see the contradiction because an algorithm for $L$ would solve $A_{TM}$. However, how can you construct $M'$ in such a way? Wouldn't that require to already have solved $A_{TM}$ to begin with? How would you notice that w is rejected or accepted without using $A_{TM}$ and how would you build the Turing machine $M'$ based on that observation in more detail? I am quite confused about that. It seems contradictory to me, in a way. I hope someone can help me with that!

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Its certainly hard (or not intuitive) to why its possible to do such a reduction, since it intuitively says that we know how to solve $A_{TM}$. The key point lies in constructing $M'$ in such a way that we won't need to know beforehand if $M$ accepts or rejects $w$.

Since this question has been asked before, take a look at [my answer for it](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141374/prove-that-the-language-l-codem-lm-textis-closed-under-reversal/141376#141376)